# List of Applescript terms from Xcode

Tags: xcode, applescript

Can someone point me to a list of xcode terms that are available for use in xcode user scripts?

Example scripts begin with the line:

using terms from application "Xcode"

-which implies there are a set of terms that are relevant to xcode.

My googling hasn't turned anything up.

Thanks, Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you see `tell whatever` or `using terms from application whatever`, look for `whatever.sdef` for documentation of the terms it understands.  `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app` will even help you with this (File > Open Dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

Open AppleScript Editor and select Window->Library. This will display a list of Applications. Double-click an Application in this list to open up it's AppleScript API.

If the Application you want (XCode in this case) isn't in the Library Window, press the '+' icon at the top and tell the library where XCode lives. This should make XCode appear in the list.